# PowerShell array with hashtable

Tags: powershell

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but I need some help with this code. 
I am trying to read IPs from some files on a bunch of servers and then output those onto screen and export to CSV. So far, I have written this.

```
$Servers = @('server1', 'server2', 'server3')
$export = @()
foreach ($server in $Servers) {

$filePath = "\\$server\d:\application\application.log"
$ipsFailed = Get-Content $filePath | Select-String "Could not resolve" | ForEach-Object {($_.tostring()).split()[-1]} | Select-Object -Unique
$export += New-Object psobject -Property @{
    ipsFailed = $ipsFailed
    }

$export
$exportFile| Export-Csv "ipsFailed.csv" -NoTypeInformation
}
```

When I run this code (without the export), I get this on screen, which is not what I want. I want more of a linear table than this array? Needless to say the export is of no use.

```
ipsFailed                     
-------------                     
{192.168.141.161, 192.168.141.162}
{192.168.141.161, 192.168.141.162}
{192.168.141.160, 192.168.141.162}
```

I know I am on the right track because running below command returns what I want, this is only for 1 server though but how do I get this into a hashtable to work for multiple servers without screwing up the output? Help.

```
PS C:\> Get-Content $filePath | Select-String "Could not resolve" | ForEach-Object {($_.tostring()).split()[-1]} | Select-Object -Unique
192.168.141.160
192.168.141.162
```

Comment: Probably needs the summary line changed, not a hash table in sight.

Comment: As noted below, can't have ':' in a share name but suspect this is just a transcription typo and the (assumed to be) running version had d$. The $ does not need to be quoted (with \`) since variable substitution in a "" string only occurs if the $ is followed by an identifier (something that could be a variable name even if it doesn't exist),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- A share name can't have a colon inside
- assign the output of both foreach to a variable gathering all output
- use a [PSCustomObject]

```
$Servers = @('server1', 'server2', 'server3')

$export = foreach ($server in $Servers) {
    $filePath = "\\$server\d`$\application\application.log"
    Get-Content $filePath | Select-String -Pattern "Could not resolve"| ForEach-Object{
        [PSCustomObject]@{
           ipsFailed = ($_ -split ' ')[-1]
        }
    }
} | Select-Object ipsFailed -Unique
$export
$export | Export-Csv "ipsFailed.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: AFAIK this won't work because you can't pipe the output of a foreach loop. Syntactically, the } at the end of the foreach (...){...} is a statement terminator so a command like

Comment: `foreach ($item in $list) { $item } | Measure-Object` will parse as `foreach ($item in $list) { $item } ; | Measure-Object`, that is, it is actually two separate commands with no input to the second command. (Needs PSv7 ?)

Comment: You can't pipe from foreach ( ) unless it's surrounded by & { } .  Or pipe from $export on the next line.

Comment: or surrounded by () to turn it into an expression (see my answer). My comment is intended to elicit a fix from the author while giving a reasoned explanation of the "empty pipe element" error for new programmers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the original code is that the result for each server is an array of (string) unique IPv4 addresses which is then assigned to a single member of a `psobject`. This (single) object is then appended to the array `$export` thus creating an array of arrays (which looks like the sample output when displayed). It also has duplicated addresses since each server is treated separately when eliminating duplicates.

The answer by user6811411 is (actually syntactically incorrect by trying to pipe the output of a `foreach` loop but seems to be intending to be) creating a stream of non-unique objects each containing only one address and then filtering the stream to eliminate any duplicates. This method would produce the desired output (if rewritten to be syntactically correct) but unless you actually want an array of objects with an "ipsFailed" member for some other purpose, it's simpler to get an array of the address strings by filtering a stream of strings

```
$Servers = @('server1', 'server2', 'server3')
$export = (foreach ($server in $Servers) {

  $filePath = "\\$server\d`$\application\application.log"

  Get-Content $filePath |
    Select-String "Could not resolve" |
    ForEach-Object {($_.tostring()).split()[-1]}

}) | Select-Object -Unique

$export
$export | Set-Content "ipsFailed.csv"
}
```

Note: Placed () around the `foreach` loop to turn it into an expression instead of a statement. Also, `Export-Csv` is a bit excessive for a one member object and now we don't even have that so a file of the addresses is easily created using `Set-Content`. This would look exactly like the *desired* output sample. If `Export-Csv` output is required, a tiny bit of fiddling adds the 'column header' (Set + Add-Content) and the quotes around the address that `Export-Csv` would produce (string subexpression). Further, `Select-String` performs a regular expression match and outputs regular expression `Match` objects thus requiring the `ToString`. It's possibly more efficient to just combine it all into the `ForEach-Object`. Other tidy-up - don't need @().

```
$Servers = 'server1', 'server2', 'server3'
$export = (foreach ($server in $Servers) {

  $filePath = "\\$server\d`$\application\application.log"

  Get-Content $filePath |
    ForEach-Object {
      if ($_ -match 'Could not resolve.*?([^ ]*)$') {
        """$($matches[1])"""
      }
    }
}) | Select-Object -Unique

$export
Set-Content ipsFailed.csv '"ipsFailed"'
$export | Add-Content ipsFailed.csv
}
```

Finally, here's a version with minimal commands by utilizing parameters, eliminating unnecessary variables, not displaying the result (export file only) and not looking like `Export-Csv`.

```
'server1', 'server2', 'server3' |
  ForEach-Object {
    Select-String -Pattern 'Could not resolve.*?([^ ]*)$' -LiteralPath "\\$_\d`$\application\application.log" |
      ForEach-Object { $_.matches[0].groups[1].value }
  } | Select-Object -Unique | Set-Content ipsFailed.csv
```